# ExifTool, apply default.xmp to all RAW images in the folder

Tags: exiftool, xmp

I have folder with files

```
default.xmp
_DSC0001.ARW
_DSC0002.ARW
_DSC0003.ARW
```

What i want to get is three new XMP files that have same contents as `default.xmp` for each image in the folder.

```
default.xmp
_DSC0001.ARW
_DSC0001.xmp
_DSC0002.ARW
_DSC0002.xmp
_DSC0003.ARW
_DSC0003.xmp
```

Comment: What is the value of `crs:RawFileName` in `default.xmp`. Are all 3 images have taken with same camera, same lens, same focal length, same aperture, shutter speed, orientation, same ISO? What is your OS?

Comment: @RomeoNinov `default.xmp` file has no entry `crs:RawFileName`  its simply settings saved from **Adobe Camera Raw** using `Save Settings...` dialog, however it works fine and **ACR** loads `.xmp` when opening `.arw` if `.xmp` has same filename. Images taken with same camera, same lens, same focal length, same aperture, **different** shutter speed, same ISO, orientation same, however i dont see how this matter because i might be just adding single setting e.g. **Dehaze** or **Saturation** inside `default.xmp` then it can apply perfectly fine to any image even if taken from different cameras.

Comment: As this is save from ACR why you do not open all the required images in ACR and load this XMP to apply the settings

Comment: @RomeoNinov because in reality i need to do this trick for thousands of images on my HDD, not just three files. Please don't ask me why unless you know the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be [Example #13](https://exiftool.org/metafiles.html#EX13) on the Metadata Sidecar Files page except instead of using `-TagsFromFile @` you would hardcode it to your default file, `-TagsFromFile /path/to/default.xmp`.

You would set the `-ext` (`-extension`) option to the type of file you want to process, e.g. `-ext ARW`, or if you want to included all files, you would use `--ext xmp` to avoid processing any existing xmp files.

`exiftool -ext ARW -TagsFromFile /path/to/default.xmp -srcfile %d%f.xmp -r DIR`

[Exiftool forum post](https://exiftool.org/forum/index.php?topic=14814.0)